# Multirow PDFAnnotationTextWidget in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to create an editable pdf annotation in pdfkit which is multirow. The user does not need to be able to create new rows, but I want the text to be displayed over the entire bounding box (i.e. on several lines).

However it seems that it uses a standard single line NSTextField when it is in editing mode. If I just could access that object I could change it to multiline but it seems that PDFAnnotationTextWidget does not expose this object.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFAnnotationTextWidget_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Any ideas?

The only example I found is the example project for PDFKit from 2006, but it also only support single line annotations.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/Introduction/Intro.html

If not possible, is there a way to create custom PDFKit annotations, and in that case, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no public method to access that NSTextField.
You can access it only swizzling some methods, like I did in [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8n2gn0u7yq6o4sr/PDFAnnotationEditor.zip) (please note: the code has a lot of warnings because it's old)

In my example you can write multiple lines in the NSTextField, but when you exit editing mode all goes on a single line: there is a reason why Apple used a single line text field for Widget annotations, AFAIK Widget annotations in PDF supports only single line, but this is a limitation on the PDF annotations and not in the Apple SDK.

If you save the document after the annotation is added, you can access it from any other pdf editor...and in that case you will see only a single line (that is not an NSTextField but the own implementation of the pdf reader).

If you want to permit to the user to write text on multiple lines, and to visualize it over the PDF (but without the possibility for the other pdf readers to change your annotations), you have to subclass `PDFAnnotation` and create your own class.
In this case, have a look a the `MyStampAnnotation` file. You can create a similar class, inheriting from `PDFAnnotation`. When the user clicks on the annotation (in editing mode), add your own textfield, then write the text directly on the document using something like `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` in the `drawWithBox:` method

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not want multiline in that sense that users should be able to insert new rows, but rather that the text should be displayed over the entire bounding box if longer than the width. So there should be no violation of the PDF widget support, but rather how it is presented with PDFKit. Is this easier? Will look into your project in the mean time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change the size of the widget if the text is longer than its size. AFAIK this can be done only while in editing mode (illegal solution: with the swizzle method changing the size of the text view, legal solution: creating your own PDFAnnotation), but not during the presentation (and with an external pdf reader). So, using the example project, you have to switch in editing mode while writing, change the size of the annotation, and switch again in presentation mode while ended.